# Count number of less than 5 minute apart intervals per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I have a table looking as follows:

[image: Raw data]

I need to group the data by Cat and Timestamp and give a count per group.  A group is defined as a 5 minute time window that is dynamic, meaning it can span across different hours.

The results of the query should give the following:

[image: Results]

Look at the first table groups in yellow.  Those groups should be detected and be counted as one, whereas the non-highlighted groups should also be counted as one

Now there are many solutions that I've read on Stackoverflow, with the following that I've tried which were relevant:

- Create time interval groups of 5 minutes - this does not work, as timestamps spanning over different hours are not matched as the same group
- Use ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Timestamp) and join on t1.Cat = t2.Cat and t1.rn + 1 = t2.rn .  Filter by DATEDIFF.  This does not work, as only pairs of two can be detected.  What if 5 timestamps sequentially are within 5 minutes?

I will really appreciate any help with this

See below for raw data in ascii table

**Raw Data**

```
+---------------------+----------+
|      Timestamp      | Category |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2018-10-01 04:06:12 | Cat1     |
| 2018-10-01 05:07:18 | Cat1     |
| 2018-10-01 05:07:19 | Cat1     |
| 2018-10-01 05:07:20 | Cat1     |
| 2018-10-01 06:09:29 | Cat1     |
| 2018-10-01 07:24:12 | Cat2     |
| 2018-10-01 07:30:43 | Cat2     |
| 2018-10-01 07:59:13 | Cat2     |
| 2018-10-01 08:02:15 | Cat2     |
| 2018-10-01 10:09:25 | Cat2     |
| 2018-10-01 11:13:42 | Cat2     |
+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Shouldnt the first record be included"2018-10-01 05:06:12" be considered since the next available value mis 05:07 which is within the 5 min window?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  My apologies, will fix the picture

Comment: I've changed the first timestamp so the table should be correct now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it

First Step categorize the records into based on whether the previous timestamp value is within 5 minutes.
If yes then assign a row_number to it.

What this will do is to get your values as follows

```
+---------------------+----------+-----------+
|     timestamp1      | category | grps_of_5 |
+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| 01/10/2018 05:06:12 | Cat1     |         1 |
| 01/10/2018 05:07:18 | Cat1     |           |
| 01/10/2018 05:07:19 | Cat1     |           |
| 01/10/2018 05:07:20 | Cat1     |           |
| 01/10/2018 06:09:29 | Cat1     |         5 |
| 01/10/2018 07:24:12 | Cat2     |         1 |
| 01/10/2018 07:30:43 | Cat2     |         2 |
| 01/10/2018 07:59:13 | Cat2     |         3 |
| 01/10/2018 08:02:15 | Cat2     |           |
| 01/10/2018 10:09:25 | Cat2     |         5 |
| 01/10/2018 11:13:42 | Cat2     |         6 |
+---------------------+----------+-----------+


After that i "copy" the values to fill up the nulls in groups using
max(grps_of_5) over(partition by category order by timestamp1)


This is done in the curated_data block and will look like this

+---------------------+----------+-----------+---------+
|     timestamp1      | category | grps_of_5 | max_val |
+---------------------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 01/10/2018 04:06:12 | Cat1     |         1 |       1 |
| 01/10/2018 05:07:18 | Cat1     |         2 |       2 |
| 01/10/2018 05:07:19 | Cat1     |           |       2 |
| 01/10/2018 05:07:20 | Cat1     |           |       2 |
| 01/10/2018 06:09:29 | Cat1     |         5 |       5 |
| 01/10/2018 07:24:12 | Cat2     |         1 |       1 |
| 01/10/2018 07:30:43 | Cat2     |         2 |       2 |
| 01/10/2018 07:59:13 | Cat2     |         3 |       3 |
| 01/10/2018 08:02:15 | Cat2     |           |       3 |
| 01/10/2018 10:09:25 | Cat2     |         5 |       5 |
| 01/10/2018 11:13:42 | Cat2     |         6 |       6 |
+---------------------+----------+-----------+---------+


After that i am counting the distinct max_val which will tell count all 5 minute intervals as a single group and others seperately.

with raw_data
  as(select timestamp1
            ,category
            ,case when datediff(mi,lag(timestamp1) over(partition by category order by timestamp1),timestamp1) >5 
                    or lag(timestamp1) over(partition by category order by timestamp1) is null
                  then row_number() over(partition by category order by timestamp1)                  
              end as grps_of_5
       from t  
     )
   ,curated_data
      as (select max(grps_of_5) over(partition by category order by timestamp1) as max_val
                 ,x.*
            from raw_data x
           )
 select category,count(distinct max_val) as cnt
   from curated_data
group by category            

+----------+------+
| category | cnt2 |
+----------+------+
| Cat1     |    3 |
| Cat2     |    5 |
+----------+------+
```

Edited version

Demo Link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=556e0ec16bb040b96b637e3da3e8178b

Comment: The first timestamp changed to '2018-10-01 04:06:12' so just make sure you have the same when building your table.  Running the query on the link you gave me gives 5 and 6 count instead of 3 and 5 count for cat1 and cat2 respectively

Comment: How is the cat-2 having an expected count of 5?. There are only two rows in that group

Comment: There are 6 rows in Cat2.  One group of 'duplicates' (within 5 minutes).  Thus the total count should be 5

Comment: Timestamps within 5 minutes count as one group.

Comment: So you want a running total of the counts within 5 minutes. Cat-2(3 from Cat1 + 2 from Cat-2)?

Comment: Haha no not a running total.  The cats should be counted separately.  Assuming a simple group by for days, it should be GROUP BY Category,Timestamp.  However instead of grouping by static values for Timestamp, it should be a 5 minute bracket that can span across hours.  So basically:

GROUP BY Category, Timestamps within 5 minutes of each other

Comment: I got that, but according to the screen shot you have 3 records which match Cat-1 that are in 5 mintutes of each other and 2 records which match Cat-2 that are in 5 minutes of each other. The final result you look for is Cat-1 -> 3 and Cat-2 -> (2 + 3). Isnt it

Comment: @ceds I don't see how Cat2 has 5 records within 5 minutes. Could you re-color the top picture, yellow lines for Cat2?

Comment: I think you understand correctly, but I need the inverse of what you are saying.  The highlighted rows should be counted as ONE.  The non-highlighted rows should also be counted.  Cat1 has 3 unique groups (meaning those three groups are outside of 5 minuts of each other), and Cat2 has 5 unique groups.  I need the count of the unique groups for each category.  Hope this makes more sense

Comment: okies, got it now. I have updated my sql query and the dbfiddle link.

Comment: That is some serious SQL Kung-Fu.  Thanks man much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, you can use the following link, I have included the value you have entered . https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b40fbb8752773b29738cb46e23f3975

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph I deleted my comment, I was wrong, the script is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with `LAG`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (timestamp DATETIME, category VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2018-10-01 04:06:12', 'CAT1'),
('2018-10-01 05:07:18', 'CAT1'),
('2018-10-01 05:07:19', 'CAT1'),
('2018-10-01 05:07:20', 'CAT1'),
('2018-10-01 06:09:29', 'CAT1'),
('2018-10-01 07:24:12', 'CAT2'),
('2018-10-01 07:30:43', 'CAT2'),
('2018-10-01 07:59:13', 'CAT2'),
('2018-10-01 08:02:15', 'CAT2'),
('2018-10-01 10:09:25', 'CAT2'),
('2018-10-01 11:13:42', 'CAT2');

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT timestamp, category, CASE WHEN LAG(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY timestamp) > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, timestamp) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM @t
)
SELECT category, COUNT(CASE WHEN chg = 1 THEN 1 END)
FROM cte1
GROUP BY category
```

To understand how it works, focus on how `chg` column is calculated and look at the results of the cte:

```
timestamp                  category    chg
2018-10-01 04:06:12.000    CAT1        1
2018-10-01 05:07:18.000    CAT1        1
2018-10-01 05:07:19.000    CAT1        0
2018-10-01 05:07:20.000    CAT1        0
2018-10-01 06:09:29.000    CAT1        1
2018-10-01 07:24:12.000    CAT2        1
2018-10-01 07:30:43.000    CAT2        1
2018-10-01 07:59:13.000    CAT2        1
2018-10-01 08:02:15.000    CAT2        0
2018-10-01 10:09:25.000    CAT2        1
2018-10-01 11:13:42.000    CAT2        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp
FROM(
    SELECT '2018-10-01 05:06:12' AS Timestamp , 'Cat1' AS Category   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 05:07:18' AS Timestamp , 'Cat1' AS Category  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 05:07:19' AS Timestamp , 'Cat1' AS Category  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 05:07:20' AS Timestamp , 'Cat1' AS Category 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 06:09:29' AS Timestamp , 'Cat1' AS Category 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 07:24:12' AS Timestamp , 'Cat2' AS Category   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 07:30:43' AS Timestamp , 'Cat2' AS Category  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 07:59:13' AS Timestamp , 'Cat2' AS Category  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 08:02:15' AS Timestamp , 'Cat2' AS Category 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 10:09:25' AS Timestamp , 'Cat2' AS Category 
   UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-01 11:13:42' AS Timestamp , 'Cat2' AS Category 
) AS T

SELECT  Category AS [Group], COUNT(CONVERT(DATE,Timestamp)) AS [Count]  FROM #temp GROUP By Category
```